# Source that the snake's contamination returned with the sin of the Golden Calf

Tags: sources-mekorot, golden-calf-egel

The gemarra in [Shabbos 146a](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.146a.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) teaches

> שבא נחש על חוה הטיל בה זוהמא ישראל שעמדו על הר סיני פסקה זוהמתן
>
> The snake came upon Eve, i.e., when it seduced her to eat from the Tree of Knowledge, it infected her with moral contamination. When the Jewish people stood at Mount Sinai, their contamination ceased

However, I have heard the idea that when the Jews sinned with the Golden Calf, this contamination came back. The earliest source I could find for this was [Nefesh HaChaim 1:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Nefesh_HaChaim.1.6.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> וע''י חטא העגל חזרה אותה הזוהמא ונתערבה בתוכם כבתחלה . וזש''ה (הושע ו׳:ז׳) והמה כאדם עברו ברית

What's the source for his statement (I don't mean the verse he brings)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I subsequently found that this statement is sourced in the Zohar I *parshas Chayei Sarah* p. 126b

> אמר רבי יוסי האי דאמרת בקדמיתא דכד נחש אתא על חוה אטיל בה זוהמא שפיר אבל הא תנינן דכד קאימו ישראל על טורא דסיני פסק מנייהו זוהמא, ישראל דקבילו אורייתא פסק מנייהו זוהמא אבל שאר עמין עעכו"ם דלא קבילו אורייתא לא פסקא זוהמא מנייהו, א"ל שפיר קאמרת אבל תא חזי אורייתא לא אתייהיבת אלא לדכורי דכתיב (דברים ד') וזאת התורה אשר שם משה לפני בני ישראל דהא נשי פטירין מפקודי אורייתא ועוד **דאהדרו כלהו לזוהמתן כקדמיתא בתר דחטו**

It just says that after the Jews sinned the contamination returned. It doesn't clarify which sin, but I guess the context makes it obvious that it's referring to the sin of the Golden Calf. This is how the Chida in his Nitzotzei Oros ad. loc. § 1 understood it, and how the Sulam ad. loc. explains it. The Chida also says this is discussed by the Zohar Chadash, but I'm not sure yet where.

Thanks to @shmosel there's also explicit mention in Zohar I *parshas Bereishis* p. 52b and Zohar II *parshas Ki Sisa* p. 193b:

> ישראל בשעתא דקיימו ישראל על טורא דסיני אתעבר מנייהו זוהמא דהאי חיויא דהא כדין בטול יצר הוה מעלמא...
> **כיון דחטאו בעגל** אתעבר מנייהו כל אינון דרגין ונהורין עלאין

I also found it in Zohar Chadash *Rus* p. 83b, although it doesn't seem to be the one the Chida is referencing.

It's interesting to me that the editions of Nefesh HaChaim I saw don't cite this Zohar, even though they cite other Zohars he's referencing. I guess they didn't realize the source...

Comment: It's more explicit here: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%96%D7%94%D7%A8_%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%A7_%D7%90_%D7%A0%D7%91_%D7%91

Comment: And here: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%96%D7%94%D7%A8_%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%A7_%D7%91_%D7%A7%D7%A6%D7%92_%D7%91

Comment: @shmosel thanks!

Answer (score 3):

His source may be [the Alshich's commentary to Vayikra 21](https://www.sefaria.org/Alshich_on_Torah%2C_Leviticus.21.1.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), which is based on his understanding of a Midrash (P. Chukas):

> וכמאמרם ז"ל (מס' שבת פ' חבית) ישראל שעמדו על הר סיני פסקה זוהמתן..... אך אחרי כן על ידי העגל חזרה הזוהמא למקומה
>   .....וזה מאמרם (שם במדרש) ז"ל כי העגל טינף פלטין של מלך כי האדם הוא פלטין משכן מלכו של עולם כי היכל ה' הוא. ומה גם במ"ת שעליהם השרה שכינתו יתברך וזה טינפו שהחזיר בו זוהמת נחש וטימא נפשו ויעכר גופו