# What is the earliest reference of the "original sin"?

Tags: sources-mekorot, theology, sin, genesis-bereishith

The term "חטא הקדמון", or "חטא אדם הראשון" is used widely in Kabalistic and Musar literature to explain Jewish theology, where the world is seen as somewhat broken by this "primordial sin", should be repaired by Mitzvos, and will be returned to the original perfection by the Messiah.

What is the earliest reference to Adam's eating the fruit (*or laying prematurely with Eve, or wasting his seed*) as the cardinal, original, or primordial sin - the Mega sin that spurred the fall of humanity and contaminated every human ever since?

Comment: Shabbos 146A (Avodah Zara 22B) the snake put a “zuhama”, which sefaria translates as moral contamination, into Chava which carried to all of humanity. Jews on Har Sinai removed it but the rest humanity still has it.

Comment: @Chatzkel: I thought we got it back 40 days later, with cheit ha'eigel.

Comment: @micha I heard that as well but from these 2 Gemaras it seems that the effect of removing it once helped even after we got it back, and that there is still a physical and mental difference between Jews and Non- Jews. See the full discussion in those 2 places

Comment: @MichaBerger https://parshaponders.com/behar-5779/#_ftn17 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/104021/1739

Comment: @Chatzkel Please post it as your answer.

Comment: It doesn’t exactly say that it was the sin of eating the forbidden fruit but rather the snake having a relation with Eva which is why I posted a comment instead